# How to loop through nested array in descending order from highest hierarchy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a nested array with 3 level of hierarchies and I would like to sort it in descending order from the highest hierarchy to the lowest based on position. The original array is as below:

```
 [{'holder': 'Passive', 'Position': 500.0, 
      'Node': [{'holder': 'TD Inc.', 'Position': 100.0, 
                  'Node': [{'holder': 'TD ETF', 'Position': 20}, 
                           {'holder': 'TD Fund', 'Position': 80}]}, 
               {'holder": 'CIBC', 'Position':400,
                  'Node':[{'holder':'CIBC Fund','Position': 400}]}]},
 {'holder': 'Active', 'Position': 550.0, 
      'Node': [{'holder': '18 Asset', 'Position': 550, 
                 'Node': [{'holder': '18 Inc.', 'Position': 250, 
                          {'holder': 'Lysander-18', 'Position': 300}]}]}];
```

and the result should be:

```
[{'0': 'Active', '1':'', '2':'','3': 550.0},
{'0': '', '1':'18 Asset', '2':'','3': 550.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'Lysander-18','3': 300.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'18 Inc.','3': 250.0},
{'0': 'Passive', '1':'', '2':'','3': 500.0},
{'0': '', '1':'CIBC', '2':'','3': 400.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'CIBC Fund','3': 400.0},
{'0': '', '1':'TD Inc.', 'Owner_name':'','3': 100.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'TD Fund','3': 80.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'TD ETF','3': 20.0}]
```

Here's the code I have right now:

```
var result = [];
function flatten(items,layer) {
    if (items) {
      items.reverse().forEach(function(a) {
        if (layer == 0) {
            result.push({
                0: a.holder,
                1: '',
                2: '',
                3: a.Position
            });
            flatten(a.Node, layer+1);
        } else if (layer == 1) {
            result.push({
                0: '',
                1: a.holder,
                2: '',
                3: a.Position
            });
            flatten(a.Node, layer+1);
        } else {
            result.push({
                0: '',
                1: '',
                2: a.holder,
                3: a.Position
            });
        }
      });
    }
    return result;
  }
```

And here's the result from my code:

```
{'0': 'Passive', '1':'', '2':'','3': 500.0},
{'0': '', '1':'CIBC', '2':'','3': 400.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'CIBC Fund','3': 400.0},
{'0': '', '1':'TD Inc.', 'Owner_name':'','3': 100.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'TD Fund','3': 80.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'TD ETF','3': 20.0},
[{'0': 'Active', '1':'', '2':'','3': 550.0},
{'0': '', '1':'18 Asset', '2':'','3': 550.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'Lysander-18','3': 300.0},
{'0': '', '1':'', '2':'18 Inc.','3': 250.0}]
```

What it does is finding the largest number in the lowest hierarchy ('CIBC Fund'' in this case - from inside to outside, but what I want is to filter from outside to inside ('Active') then goes to the next level).

A sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The keys `Orientation`, `Parent_Owner` and `Owner_name` do not show up in your sample data, they don't show up in your code attempt - how do they get into your expected results?

Comment: Your data isn't valid. Secondarily, you have an array with an object in it, and in that object there are objects that have arrays. It looks very muddled and it's difficult to make sense of how you're determining what goes where in your result, not to mention what should be assigned to each key name. Could you make this more clear?

Comment: Please see above. Thanks!